# Plesk + Python Flask - Configuring proxy on second website does not work

Tags: python, nginx, flask, vps, plesk

I have an issue when I run two python flask websites. The port forwarding does not work for the second website.

My starting points are two html hello-world websites accessible via domain names.
I removed the HTML index files and started python flask

```
waitress-serve --port 8080 --call "mysite_1:myflaskentrypoint"
```

mysite_1.com:8080 -> accessible (Ok for now)

I entered the following config in Plesk -> Home -> Domains -> mysite_1 -> Appache & nginx Settings -> Additional nginx directives.

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
}
```

https://mysite_1.com accessible (great)

Now comes the issue with the second website.

```
waitress-serve --port 9080 --call "mysite_2:myflaskentrypoint"
```

mysite_2.com:9080 -> accessible (Ok for now)

Plesk -> Home -> Domains -> mysite_2 -> Appache & nginx Settings -> Additional nginx directives.

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:9080;
}
```

https://mywebsite_2.com accessible
-> ERROR 403 Forbidden

Error-Log

```
403 GET / HTTP/2.0      Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) ...    795 nginx 
SSL/TLS access
Error   ...     11691#0: *386 directory index of "/var/www/vhosts/<mysite_2>.de/httpdocs/" 
is forbidden                nginx error
```

Any hints are welcome

```
----
nginx -T

root@localhost:~# nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/zz010_psa_nginx.conf:
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/server.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/webmails/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/forwarding/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/wildcards/*.conf;
# configuration file /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

include "/etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/ip_default/*.conf";

server {
    listen <vps_ip>:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfK6DJ8w;
    ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfK6DJ8w;

    location ^~ /plesk-site-preview/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8880;
        proxy_set_header Host               plesk-site-preview.local;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_cookie_domain plesk-site-preview.local $host;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://<vps_ip>:7081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    listen <vps_ip>:80;

    location ^~ /plesk-site-preview/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8880;
        proxy_set_header Host               plesk-site-preview.local;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_cookie_domain plesk-site-preview.local $host;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<vps_ip>:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/ip_default/<website_1>.conf:
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
server {
    listen <vps_ip>:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf9FAuU9;
    ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf9FAuU9;

    server_name www.<website_1>;

    location / {
        return 301 https://<website_1>$request_uri;
    }

}

server {
    listen <vps_ip>:443 default_server ssl http2;

    server_name <website_1>;
    server_name ipv4.<website_1>;

    ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf9FAuU9;
    ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf9FAuU9;

    error_page 400 "/error_docs/bad_request.html";
    error_page 401 "/error_docs/unauthorized.html";
    error_page 403 "/error_docs/forbidden.html";
    error_page 404 "/error_docs/not_found.html";
    error_page 500 "/error_docs/internal_server_error.html";
    error_page 405 "/error_docs/method_not_allowed.html";
    error_page 406 "/error_docs/not_acceptable.html";
    error_page 407 "/error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html";
    error_page 412 "/error_docs/precondition_failed.html";
    error_page 414 "/error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html";
    error_page 415 "/error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html";
    error_page 501 "/error_docs/not_implemented.html";
    error_page 502 "/error_docs/bad_gateway.html";
    error_page 503 "/error_docs/maintenance.html";

    location ^~ /error_docs {
        root "/var/www/vhosts/<website_1>";
    }

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    root "/var/www/vhosts/<website_1>/httpdocs";
    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_1>/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_1>/logs/proxy_error_log";

    location ^~ /plesk-site-preview/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8880;
        proxy_set_header Host               plesk-site-preview.local;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_cookie_domain plesk-site-preview.local $host;
        access_log off;
    }

    #extension letsencrypt begin
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

        types { }
        default_type text/plain;

        satisfy any;
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;

        location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge.*/\. {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    #extension letsencrypt end

    #extension sslit begin

    #extension sslit end

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
        auth_basic "Domain statistics";
        auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_1>/pd/d..httpdocs@plesk-stat";
        autoindex on;

        location ~ ^/plesk-stat(.*) {
            alias /var/www/vhosts/system/<website_1>/statistics/$1;
        }

        location ~ ^/awstats-icon(.*) {
            alias /usr/share/awstats/icon/$1;
        }

        location ~ ^/(.*) {
            alias /var/www/vhosts/system/<website_1>/statistics/$1;
        }
    }

    add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;

    include "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_1>/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}
server {
    listen <vps_ip>:80;

    server_name www.<website_1>;

    location / {
        return 301 https://<website_1>$request_uri;
    }

}

server {
    listen <vps_ip>:80 default_server;

    server_name <website_1>;
    server_name ipv4.<website_1>;

    error_page 400 "/error_docs/bad_request.html";
    error_page 401 "/error_docs/unauthorized.html";
    error_page 403 "/error_docs/forbidden.html";
    error_page 404 "/error_docs/not_found.html";
    error_page 500 "/error_docs/internal_server_error.html";
    error_page 405 "/error_docs/method_not_allowed.html";
    error_page 406 "/error_docs/not_acceptable.html";
    error_page 407 "/error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html";
    error_page 412 "/error_docs/precondition_failed.html";
    error_page 414 "/error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html";
    error_page 415 "/error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html";
    error_page 501 "/error_docs/not_implemented.html";
    error_page 502 "/error_docs/bad_gateway.html";
    error_page 503 "/error_docs/maintenance.html";

    location ^~ /error_docs {
        root "/var/www/vhosts/<website_1>";
    }

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
# configuration file /var/www/vhosts/system/<website_1>/conf/vhost_nginx.conf:
location / {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/webmails/<website_2>_webmail.conf:
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

server {
    listen <vps_ip>:443 ssl;
    server_name "webmail.<website_2>";

    ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfETmI6V;
    ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfETmI6V;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    #extension sslit begin

    #extension sslit end

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://<vps_ip>:7081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    listen <vps_ip>:80;
    server_name "webmail.<website_2>";

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    #extension sslit begin

    #extension sslit end

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<vps_ip>:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/webmails/<website_1>_webmail.conf:
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

# Webmail is not enabled on the domain

# Webmail is not enabled on the domain
# configuration file /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/<website_2>.conf:
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
server {
    listen <vps_ip>:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfETmI6V;
    ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfETmI6V;

    server_name www.<website_2>;

    location / {
        return 301 https://<website_2>$request_uri;
    }

}

server {
    listen <vps_ip>:443 ssl http2;

    server_name <website_2>;
    server_name ipv4.<website_2>;

    ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfETmI6V;
    ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfETmI6V;

    error_page 400 "/error_docs/bad_request.html";
    error_page 401 "/error_docs/unauthorized.html";
    error_page 403 "/error_docs/forbidden.html";
    error_page 404 "/error_docs/not_found.html";
    error_page 500 "/error_docs/internal_server_error.html";
    error_page 405 "/error_docs/method_not_allowed.html";
    error_page 406 "/error_docs/not_acceptable.html";
    error_page 407 "/error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html";
    error_page 412 "/error_docs/precondition_failed.html";
    error_page 414 "/error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html";
    error_page 415 "/error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html";
    error_page 501 "/error_docs/not_implemented.html";
    error_page 502 "/error_docs/bad_gateway.html";
    error_page 503 "/error_docs/maintenance.html";

    location ^~ /error_docs {
        root "/var/www/vhosts/<website_2>";
    }

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    root "/var/www/vhosts/<website_2>/httpdocs";
    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/logs/proxy_error_log";

    #extension letsencrypt begin
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

        types { }
        default_type text/plain;

        satisfy any;
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;

        location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge.*/\. {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    #extension letsencrypt end

    #extension sslit begin

    #extension sslit end

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
        auth_basic "Domain statistics";
        auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/pd/d..httpdocs@plesk-stat";
        autoindex on;

        location ~ ^/plesk-stat(.*) {
            alias /var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/statistics/$1;
        }

        location ~ ^/awstats-icon(.*) {
            alias /usr/share/awstats/icon/$1;
        }

        location ~ ^/(.*) {
            alias /var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/statistics/$1;
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/<website_2>/web_users/$1/$2;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    location ~ /$ {
        index "index.html" "index.cgi" "index.pl" "index.php" "index.xhtml" "index.htm" "index.shtml";
    }

    add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;

    include "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}
server {
    listen <vps_ip>:80;

    server_name www.<website_2>;

    location / {
        return 301 http://<website_2>$request_uri;
    }

}

server {
    listen <vps_ip>:80;

    server_name <website_2>;
    server_name ipv4.<website_2>;

    error_page 400 "/error_docs/bad_request.html";
    error_page 401 "/error_docs/unauthorized.html";
    error_page 403 "/error_docs/forbidden.html";
    error_page 404 "/error_docs/not_found.html";
    error_page 500 "/error_docs/internal_server_error.html";
    error_page 405 "/error_docs/method_not_allowed.html";
    error_page 406 "/error_docs/not_acceptable.html";
    error_page 407 "/error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html";
    error_page 412 "/error_docs/precondition_failed.html";
    error_page 414 "/error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html";
    error_page 415 "/error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html";
    error_page 501 "/error_docs/not_implemented.html";
    error_page 502 "/error_docs/bad_gateway.html";
    error_page 503 "/error_docs/maintenance.html";

    location ^~ /error_docs {
        root "/var/www/vhosts/<website_2>";
    }

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    root "/var/www/vhosts/<website_2>/httpdocs";
    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/logs/proxy_access_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/logs/proxy_error_log";

    #extension letsencrypt begin
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

        types { }
        default_type text/plain;

        satisfy any;
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;

        location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge.*/\. {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    #extension letsencrypt end

    #extension sslit begin

    #extension sslit end

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/<website_2>/web_users/$1/$2;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/php-fpm.sock";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    }

    location ~ /$ {
        index "index.html" "index.cgi" "index.pl" "index.php" "index.xhtml" "index.htm" "index.shtml";
    }

    add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;

    include "/var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf:

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# https://httpoxy.org/
fastcgi_param  HTTP_PROXY         "";

# configuration file /var/www/vhosts/system/<website_2>/conf/vhost_nginx.conf:
location / { return 200 "OK \n"; }
root@localhost:~#
```

curl -v <website_2.de>

```
curl -v https://<website_2.de>
*   Trying <plesk IP>:443...
curl -v <website_2.de>

* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <website_2.de> (<plesk IP>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=<website_2.de>
*  start date: Feb 22 18:06:21 2021 GMT
*  expire date: May 23 18:06:21 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "<website_2.de>" matched cert's "<website_2.de>"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x565382a48e10)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: <website_2.de>
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 403 
< server: nginx
< date: Fri, 26 Feb 2021 08:37:59 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 795
< etag: "6033f929-31b"
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/error_docs/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Server Error</h1>
    <div class="error-code">403</div>
    <h2>Forbidden</h2>
    <p class="lead">You do not have permission to access this document.</p>
    <hr/>
    <p>That's what you can do</p>
    <div class="help-actions">
      <a href="javascript:location.reload();">Reload Page</a>
      <a href="javascript:history.back();">Back to Previous Page</a>
      <a href="/">Home Page</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
* Connection #0 to host <website_2.de> left intact
```

Comment: Do you have root access to the server as well? looks like the NGINX is not hittig that location. Try `location / { return 200 "OK \n"; }` for your second server config. Use curl for example to test the configuration `curl -v https://mywebsite_2.com/` this should return 200 OK if the configuration is correct.

Comment: Hi @TimoStark. Yes, I have root access. It is a VPS that I am using.  When I add location / { return 200 "OK \n"; } I get the same error. But I noticed that when I create an index.html file with some dummy content I get OK back. I do not have an Index.html file in the website_1. The content is dynamically created by flask.

Comment: That super weird. the return statement is in the earliest access phases of a NGINX request processing. There should be a need of having a index.html file. Is it possible to share the output of `sudo nginx -T` this would print out the whole config. I thing this will be the best option to find the issue.

Comment: @TinoStark I added the output of nginx -T to the post

Comment: How do get this error? Are you able to share the curl command? The config above looks like a normal plesk modified nginx config. Have a server on my side for testing. will do some more tests if I know what request do you send.

Comment: Hi @TinoStark I added the curl command with output below the log. What is interesting is,  if I just 'touch index.html' in the /var/www/vhosts/<website_2>.de/httpdocs I get OK back. I thought great, this will be a workaround. I can create an empty file. But if I try to set the proxy after that I get a different error. <p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>

Comment: @TinoStark  I found the solution a the end by simple try and fail. I will add the configuration that worked for me in the comment bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I found a configuration that works for me.

First I checked the box in nginx settings "Proxy mode"
I have set the proxy, not in Nginx, but in Additional Apache directives -> "Additional directives for HTTP/HTTPS"

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny, allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location "/">
    ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:9080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:9080/"
</Location>
```

This worked. I can access both flask websites via domain name.

Comment: This is httpd my friend. Not NGINX :) This could be the case!

Comment: Yes. Nginx is now set as just proxy. But this works. Is there any benifit when using nginx only and not apache and nginx as proxy?

Comment: I mean you are using as an Proxy as well... Means you are proxying the request from NGINX to Apache and then from Apache to your App... That doesn't make any sense at all. Check your Plesk App Settings... I would try to remove one proxy layer.

Comment: I was wondering why do I need both as well, but it appears it is a common setting to have NGINX in front of Apache. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562099/apache-and-nginx-together-why. This is a default setting in Plesk. And I tried to remove one layer, but if you remember the title of my question (it does not work :) )

Comment: I am running hundrets of sites without a single httpd in the chain. Main reason for that I do not need to write .htacecss files because I can simply change my nginx config. But a couple of 3rd parties have .htaccess files backed into theire codes... But based on my profession I can tell you: If your Application need!!! an .htaccess file to work you have an problem in your application code.